# Add rows to combobox dataTable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable

I want to add a new rows to the datatable in combobox but receive error when adding

```
"Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."
```

combobox: string , int
"ALL",0
"A",1
"B",2

Below is my code

```
SqlDataAdapter _dataAdapter_myReader = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable _dataTable_myReader = new DataTable();

public Form_ListAll() 
{
    _dataAdapter_myReader = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN type = '1' then 'A' WHEN type = '2' then 'B' END AS Descp, type from table ORDER BY type", myConnection);

    _dataTable_myReader.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ALL", 0 });
    _dataAdapter_myReader.Fill(_dataTable_myReader);
    _cmbBoxType.DataSource = _dataTable_myReader;
    _cmbBoxType.DisplayMember = "Descp";
    _cmbBoxType.ValueMember = "type";
    _cmbBoxType.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have two columns in the data table..? because it says that the data table doesn't contains two columns and you're trying to add a row with two column's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need first to create DataTable structure  and **Then**  add the Row with add,

_dataAdapter_myReader = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN type = '1' then 'A' WHEN type = '2' then 'B' END AS Descp, type from table ORDER BY type", myConnection);

_dataAdapter_myReader.Fill(_dataTable_myReader);

DataRow dr = callsTable.NewRow();

dr["Descp"] = "All";
  dr["type"] = "0";

_dataAdapter_myReader.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

and then populate the combobox :)

Hope this helps